# ReactJS useState is empty string when I set a value

Tags: reactjs

I have a changeStyle () function that sets values with useState (), every useState () works fine without this "setPreviousSelectedRow (currentRow);", the value is always an empty string. I have the same function in another component, I have no problem there.

This is my code:

```
const TableRow = (props) => {
const [entry, setEntry] = useState('');
const array = Object.entries(props);
const navigate = useNavigate();
const [previousSelectedId, setPreviousSelectedId] = useState('');
const [previousSelectedRow, setPreviousSelectedRow] = useState('');

const changeStyle = (e, id) => {
    setEntry(id);
    let currentRow = e.currentTarget;

    if (id === previousSelectedId) {
        currentRow.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F7FA';
        setEntry('');
        setPreviousSelectedId('');
        setPreviousSelectedRow('');
    }
    else {
        currentRow.style.backgroundColor = '#E3E5E7';

        if (previousSelectedRow) {
            previousSelectedRow.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F7FA';
        }

        setPreviousSelectedId(id);
        setPreviousSelectedRow(currentRow);
    }
};

return (
    <tr className={styles['contact-row']} onDoubleClick={navigateToDetails} key={array[1][1].id} onClick={(e) => changeStyle(e, array[1][1].id) }>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].name}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].continentAndCountry}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].email}</td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForFreeGuyz + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForFreeGuyz}>{array[1][1].accountNameForFreeGuyz}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForInstagram + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForInstagram}>{array[1][1].accountNameForInstagram}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}><a href={array[1][1].baseUrlForTwitter + '/' + array[1][1].accountNameForTwitter}>{array[1][1].accountNameForTwitter}</a></td>
        <td id={array[1][1].id}>{array[1][1].accountType}</td>
        <td>
            {entry && <>
                <button className={`btn btn-warning ${styles['edit-button']}`} id={array[1][1].id} onClick={editContact}>Edit</button>
                <button className={`btn btn-danger ${styles['delete-button']}`} id={array[1][1].id} type="submit" onClick={deleteContact}>Delete</button></>}
        </td>
    </tr>
);
}

export default TableRow;
```

Does anyone knows where the problem is ?

Comment: Is it so hard to understand that the state (`previousSelectedRow`) required is a *string*, meanwhile you are passing an *object* (`currentRow`) ? If you want it to be an object, initialize it with `{}` instead (`const [previousSelectedRow, setPreviousSelectedRow] = useState({});`)

Comment: your `PreviousSelectedRow` expects the value of the string type.

Comment: I try with object initialization but the result is empty object.